# Extracting Specific Field from String in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataframe returns the below result as `String`.

```
  QueryResult{status='success', finalSuccess=true, parseSuccess=true, allRows=[{"cbcnt":0}], signature={"cbcnt":"number"}, info=N1qlMetrics{resultCount=1, errorCount=0, warningCount=0, mutationCount=0, sortCount=0, resultSize=11, elapsedTime='5.080179ms', executionTime='4.931124ms'}, profileInfo={}, errors=[], requestId='754d19f6-7ec1-4609-bf2a-54214d06c57c', clientContextId='542bc4c8-1a56-4afb-8c2f-63d81e681cb4'}   |

  QueryResult{status='success', finalSuccess=true, parseSuccess=true, allRows=[{"cbcnt":"2021-07-30T00:00:00-04:00"}], signature={"cbcnt":"String"}, info=N1qlMetrics{resultCount=1, errorCount=0, warningCount=0, mutationCount=0, sortCount=0, resultSize=11, elapsedTime='5.080179ms', executionTime='4.931124ms'}, profileInfo={}, errors=[], requestId='754d19f6-7ec1-4609-bf2a-54214d06c57c', clientContextId='542bc4c8-1a56-4afb-8c2f-63d81e681cb4'}
```

I just want

```
"cbcnt":0  <-- Numeric part of this
```

Expected Output

```
col
----
0
2021-07-30
```

Tried:

```
.withColumn("CbRes",regexp_extract($"Col", """"cbcnt":(\S*\d+)""", 1))
```

Output

```
 col
    ----
    0
    "2021-07-30 00:00:00   --<--additional " is coming
```

Comment: There is nothing built into Spark to help you with this. You will have to use transformation to do it yourself by splitting strings using regex and such with plain Scala.

Comment: https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala#parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Pyspark function [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = <dataframe with a column "text" that contains the input data">
df.withColumn("col", F.regexp_extract("text", """"cbcnt":(\d+)""", 1)).show()
```

Comment: Works well.. Thnx

Comment: When `"cbcnt": "2021-07-30T00:00:00-04:00"` inplace of digit then what i need to do. "\d+" takes only digit. I want the date part ie. `2021-07-30`

Comment: @VnS you can try `df.withColumn("col", F.regexp_extract("text", """"cbcnt":"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*".""", 1)).show()`

Comment: This doesn't give the correct result. Column now becomes `null`. My column has `Numeric` plus `date` content as string. I want something which pick anything which comes after `cbcnt` either number of date.

Comment: @VnS I don't quite understand if you only want to get the date part or anything after `cbcnt`. Maybe you could create a new question with example input data and the expected output?

Comment: I modified the question clearly. Am not sure what's not clear to you. I already showed yhe data in my dataframe.. showed expected output. Tell me what else is needed.

Comment: @VnS you are right: I only checked your comments and didn't look at the question again.... you could try `df.withColumn("col", F.concat(F.regexp_extract("text", """"cbcnt":(\d+)""", 1), F.regexp_extract("text", """"cbcnt":"(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)T.*".""", 1)))` to combine the 2 regexps as `regexp_extract` returns an empty string if no match is found.`

Answer (score 1):

Extract via regex:

```
val value = "QueryResult{status='success', finalSuccess=true, parseSuccess=true, allRows=[{\"cbcnt\":0}], signature={\"cbcnt\":\"number\"}, info=N1qlMetrics{resultCount=1, errorCount=0, warningCount=0, mutationCount=0, sortCount=0, resultSize=11, elapsedTime='5.080179ms', executionTime='4.931124ms'}, profileInfo={}, errors=[], requestId='754d19f6-7ec1-4609-bf2a-54214d06c57c', clientContextId='542bc4c8-1a56-4afb-8c2f-63d81e681cb4'}   |"
val regex = """"cbcnt":(\d+)""".r.unanchored
val s"${regex(result)}" = value

println(result)
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: This is erroring out. The error is as below: `method s is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
val s"${regex(result)}" = value`

Comment: @vnsingh Then your version of Scala < 2.13. Starting Scala 2.13 add [this](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]])

Comment: Nevertheless, I believe that Werner's answer is more correct. Since it is in the context of using a Apache-Spark.

Comment: When `"cbcnt": "2021-07-30T00:00:00-04:00"` inplace of digit then what i need to do. "\d+" takes only digit. I want the date part ie. `2021-07-30`

Comment: `allRows.*?cbcnt":(.*?)}`

Comment: Used `df.withColumn("Col1",regexp_extract($"Col", """"cbcnt":(.*?)""", 1))` -- This doesnt work

Comment: @VnS You are using a another regex. And yes, your regex isn't working :)

Comment: Any solutions you have ? I mean I know the regex not working :-)

Comment: I wrote above, but you used another one